# Implement Ionic 2 Model by Using Interfaces and Class

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

When declare a Model inside Ionic 2, I saw that there are two of doing it. Through Interface or Class

Interface code:

```
export interface BlogPost {
  postId: number,
  title: string
}
```

Class code:

```
export class BlogPost{
  public object: {};
  constructor(
    public postId: number,
    public title: string
  ) {
    this.object = {
      postId: this.postId,
      title: this.title,
    };
  }
}
```

I am not sure what is the difference between them and is there any ways that we can also declare a predefined value in advance in Ionic 2. Like

```
export interface BlogPost {
  postId: number,
  title: string,
  comments: string = 'Test'
}
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I should read this blog about classes and interfaces in TypeScript: https://toddmotto.com/classes-vs-interfaces-in-typescript

Still not sure how to predefined a variable. Maybe it's not possible because the Model is mainly for type checking.

Answer (score 0):

You're right - the interface is for type checking. Take a look at this [documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html). If you want to declare variables of a certain type, create a class and then declare an object to be of that class type.

E.g.

```
// This interface declares that an object must have a 'name' attribute.
interface IPerson {
    name: string;
}

// This class, which implements IPerson, must have a 'name' attribute.
class Person implements IPerson {
    name: string;
    age: number;
    address: string;
}

// We can assume that the argument has a 'name' attribute,
// because the parameter is of type IPerson.
showName(p: IPerson) {
    console.log(p.name);
}

let someone: Person = new Person();
this.showName(someone);
```